# Which versions of programming languages are supported by Apiary's code samples capability?

Tags: sample, apiary

Apiary auto generates code samples. Many languages are supported (cURL, Go, Groovy, Java, JavaScript, Node.js, Objective-C, Perl, Python, PHP, Raw, Ruby, Swift, Visual Basic).

Two questions:
1. Which versions of the languages are supported?
2. Does anyone using Apiary need to set up automated tests for the auto generated code samples?

Answer (score 0):

1. That's a good question. The versions are not displayed currently, but the team responsible for the functionality will work on that shortly.
2. You don't need to set up tests against the code samples - the samples are there to help anyone writing code making calls to the API which is being designed in Apiary.

Comment: OK. Understood. Thanks.